# Attribute error while trying to save excel file with win32

Tags: python, excel, error-handling, win32-process

The following is line 684 from code

```
try:
  xlBook.SaveAs("%s/ContingencyFile.xlsx" %(os.getcwd()))
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
except:
  xlApp.xlBook.Close
  xlBook.SaveAs("%s/ContingencyFile.xlsx" %(os.getcwd()))
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This is the error that I come across while running my program -

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "H:\proj4\combine.py", line 684, in ProcessNewFile
xlApp.xlBook.Close
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, 
in__getattr__
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Excel.Application.xlBook
```

How can i get rid of the error?

Comment: if `xlBook.SaveAs` is correct, then `xlApp.xlBook.Close` should be `xlBook.Close`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
xlBook.Close() # or xlApp.xlBook.Close() ?
```

You're not calling a method without the `()` that's why it raises this `AttributeError`.

(maybe do the `SaveAs(...)` before ?, i'm not sure... )

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggested but it didn't work and then I ran it the next day and it worked. so i assumed something I did the previous day was wrong, but it worked now. I sent the files to someone else and it gave them the same error. Why would this be happening?

Comment: does it work with `xlApp.xlBook.Close()  or xlBook.Close()` ?

Comment: Well now, I tried with both and both worked for me! I sent the one with xlApp.xlBook.close() to someone else and it didnt work for them.

Comment: the last one is better, if you can make them replace the code

Comment: xlbook.close() worked for them too!! Thanks @PRMoureu